# Multiple select box: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Please help me to find the error in the Javascript page says when selecting the multiple select box to select an option to other multiselect.

The Javascript and ASP page has the below code:

```js
function add_to(objSrc, objSkill, objList, objList1, objList2, nMaxNr, bModified) {

 var obj1 = objSrc;
 var obj2 = objList;
 var obj3;
 var obj4 = objSkill;
 var obj5 = objList1;
 var obj6 = objList2;
 var k = obj2.length;

 var leveltext = "";
 var levelvalue = "()";
 var skillSelect;

 for (var i = 0; i < obj4.length; i++) {

  if (obj4.Level[i].checked) {

   leveltext = "(" + skillValueToText(obj4.Level[i].value) + ")";
   levelvalue = "(" + obj4.Level[i].value + ")";

   break;
  }

 }

 for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {

  if (obj1.options[i].selected && obj1.options[i].value != 0) {

   if (skillsGetList(obj1, obj2, obj5, obj6)) {

    if ((nMaxNr > 0) && (nMaxNr < k)) {
     alert("You can add a maximum of " + nMaxNr + " skills.");
    } else {

     obj3 = new Option;
     obj3.text = obj1.options[i].text + leveltext;
     obj3.value = obj1.options[i].value + levelvalue;
     obj2.options[k] = obj3;
     skillsGetFocus(obj2, obj5, obj6);
     obj2.options[k].selected = true;
     k++;

     if (bModified) {
      bModified.value = 'Y';
     }
    }
   } else {
    skillSelect = obj1.options[i].text;
    alert("'" + skillSelect + "' is already on your list.");
   }

  }

 }

 return false;

}
```

```html
<select 
    id="sele_des"
    name="sele_des"
    size="10"
    onFocus= "JavaScript:window.skillsGetFocus(document.SetSkillsForm.sele_des1, document.SetSkillsForm.sele_des2, document.SetSkillsForm.sele_des3)"
    onDblClick="JavaScript:return window.add_to(document.SkillsListForm.sele_des, document.SkillsLevel, document.SetSkillsForm.sele_des1, document.SetSkillsForm.sele_des2, document.SetSkillsForm.sele_des3, -1)"
    style="width: 360px"
>
```

Comment: You're attempting to iterate an Object as if it were an Array is my first guess.

Comment: code formatting

Comment: Are you checked both `objSkill` and `objSrc` contents? Check the debugger where the TypeError came from and ensure they're both arrays.